# Find equation from one point and limit

Tags: limits, logarithms

I was wondering if it was possible to find/approximate an equation from just a single known point and the known limit.

For example,

$$f(0) = 0.8$$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \hspace{.1cm}f(x) = 1.8$$

I'm not sure what the $x$ will be at any given time. All I know is that when $x = 0, y = .8$ and, as $x$ approaches infinity, the $y$ gets closer to $1.8$.

Comment: Not really enough information...you could try something like $f(x)=-e^{-x}+1.8$.  That passes both your tests, and it's pretty simple.  But there are lots of other functions that work as well.

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you!

Comment: One can approximate anything from anything.  Whether it's a good approximation, however, is another story.

Answer (score 2):

With such a small amount of information we can't really determine a sufficiently small set of solutions, there are undoubtedly infinitely many functions which satisfy your two criteria, among whom are complicated looking ones such as, $$f(x):=
\begin{cases}
0.8, & x=0\\ 
0.8+\dfrac{x^4+10^{10^{10}}x^3-x^2+ex+\pi^\pi}{x^4+42824},   & x\neq 0
\end{cases},$$ or simpler ones, such as $f:x\mapsto -1000^{-2x}+1.8$.